Disintegration theorem with function taking negative values
I need a slightly stronger version of the disintegration theorem as stated on Wikipedia.
In particular, the theorem as stated on Wikipedia guarantees that measures  $\mu_x$ on the "slices" exist such that for every Borel-measurable function $f : Y \to [0,\infty]$,
$$\int_{Y} f(y) \, \mathrm{d} \mu (y) = \int_{X} \int_{\pi^{-1} (x)} f(y) \, \mathrm{d} \mu_x (y) \, \mathrm{d} \nu (x).$$
where $\nu(x)$ is the push forward of $\mu(y)$ by $\pi$. In my case, the function $f$ can also be negative. However, the integral $\int_{Y} f(y) \, \mathrm{d} \mu (y)$ is guaranteed to be nonnegative. Does the disintegration theorem still hold in this setting?

The answer is yes, as shown in Proposition 452F of Fremlin's Measure Theory (Vol 4.1). It is also not necessary that the integral is nonnegative. Essentially, we rewrite $f$ as the difference of its positive part $f^+$ and its negative part $f^-$, so $f=f^+-f^-$. We can then apply the theorem to $f^+$ and $f^-$ individually.
